# Multiple Word Animation in HTML using Animate.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am new to animation in HTML. I started using Animate.css and it's pretty cool. I'm trying to add animation to multiple words (rotating effect).

The code is tried so far is below.

```
<body>
     <h1 id="ani"></h1>
    <script>
        var vals = ["abc", "jkh", "xyz"];
        for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("ani");
            element.className += " animated fadeInDown delay-2s"
            var x = document.createTextNode(vals[i]);
            element.appendChild(x);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This code just displays all the 3 words and adds the animation. I want the animation to be applied to the first word & the second word & the last word.

I need help figuring this out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Vijayakrishnan , I just posted an answer to your question. Please consider giving me feedback on whether it helped you or not ^^.

Answer (score 1):

First , Use **span** tags instead of textNodes to apply css classes.
Second, you are appplying the css classes to the H1 tag. You need to add them on each element.

I added a delay on each word, just to show you how it works ^^

```js
var vals = ["abc", "jkh", "xyz"];
var element = document.getElementById("ani");
for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {   
 var spanElement = document.createElement('span')
 spanElement.innerHTML = vals[i];
 var delay = "delay-"+(i+1)+"s" ;
 spanElement.className += " animated fadeInDown "+delay ;
    element.appendChild(spanElement);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.css"/>

<h1 id="ani"></h1>
```

Here's a version without a delay on each element :) hope it helps

```js
var vals = ["abc", "jkh", "xyz"];
var element = document.getElementById("ani");
for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {   
 var spanElement = document.createElement('span')
 spanElement.innerHTML = vals[i];
 spanElement.className += " animated fadeInDown delay-2s" ;
  element.appendChild(spanElement);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.css"/>

<h1 id="ani"></h1>
```